# get value of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation (XPATH)

Tags: java, xpath, xsi

updated:

I would like to get the value of the arritbute in  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation, that is to say: "http://www.mypage/pagedescription.xsd"

```
<link 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.mypage/pagedescription.xsd">


 ...
 ...
```

link is an element in my XML File (nearly at the top)

However, the XPATH //n:link/@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation does not work

I tried to modify the context but it still does not work

```
@Override
public Object executeXpathQuery(Document domDoc, String strQuery) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("executeXpathQuery : strQuery:" + strQuery);

    // output: executeXpathQuery:  strQuery://n:link/@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
    // so far, it looks OK

    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xpf.newXPath();

    final String nonameNamespace = domDoc.getFirstChild().getNamespaceURI();

    NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {

            String uri = null;
            if ("n".equals(prefix)) {
                System.out.println("using prefix");
                uri = nonameNamespace;
            } 
            else if ("xsi".equals(prefix)) {
                 uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            }
            return null;
        }
        public String getPrefix(String uri) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
         }
    };


    xPath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

    XPathExpression xPathExp = xPath.compile(strQuery);


    return (Node) xPathExp.evaluate(domDoc,XPathConstants.NODE);

}
```

And I made the docuùent builder aware of the context:

```
    static DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilder() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
    DocumentBuilder db;

    db = null;

    try {
        dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        LogMes.log(XMLFactoryServiceImpl.class, LogMes.ERROR, "Erreur lors de la cràation d'un document DOM. Message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return db;
}
```

I get "using prefix" in the output => this part lokks OK
I still get a null value

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are 99% of the way there, you just need to make your `NamespaceContext` return the right thing for the `xsi` prefix:

```
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {

        String uri = null;
        if ("n".equals(prefix)) {
            System.out.println("using prefix");
            uri = nonameNamespace;
        } else if ("xsi".equals(prefix)) {
            uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

Also, if you are creating the `domDoc` by parsing XML using a `DocumentBuilder` then you must ensure that the builder is namespace-aware by calling `docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)` before `.newDocumentBuilder()`.  For what I can only presume are historical reasons, the default for DBF is to parse *without* handling namespaces, and such a DOM tree won't work with XPath.

Comment: I have taken into account the modifications you proposed, but I still got a null. However, thanks a lot for your kindness !

Comment: @user3166206 is the `link` element itself in a namespace (i.e. is there an ancestor element with a default `xmlns="..."` declaration)?  If so you probably need `n:link` in the XPath rather than just `link`.